# BoneCP:Bad URL format

Tags: java, spring, bonecp

I'm using the following bonecp configuration to achieve connection pooling using BoneCP.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="60" />
        <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="240" />
        <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="5" />
        <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="1" />
        <property name="partitionCount" value="3" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5" />
        <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100" />
    </bean>
```

It throws exception :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xyz, username = root. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad URL format
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.parseURL(Utils.java:185)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:84)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:351)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:630)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:737)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:805)
    at org.core.common.security.dao.UserDAO.loadUserByUsername(UserDAO.java:31)
    at org.core.common.security.service.UserService.loadUserByUsername(UserService.java:20)
    at org.core.common.security.CustomAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CustomAuthenticationProvider.java:29)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
------

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolUtil.generateSQLException(PoolUtil.java:192)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:422)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad URL format
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.parseURL(Utils.java:185)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:84)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:351)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
    ... 44 more
```

The URL is perfectly alright. Also, exception contains "org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.parseURL". How is hive related to this ? Am i going wrong some where ?

But this plain configuration works fine.

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
         class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    </bean>
```

I understand there would not be any code change to use plain and bonecp configuration. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Judging from the stack trace you aren't using the correct driver. Shouldn't you be using the MySQL driver, looks like you are using some other driver for this.

Comment: I'm using 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. Yes, @M. Deinum is right. Though i'm using mysql driver, its misleading to hive related stuff.

Comment: Problem resolved: I'm using <bean id="hive-driver" class="org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"/> for hive related stuff. Commented this and problem solved. Still i don't understand, without any  reference to hive-driver from dataSource bean: how is dataSource picking hive-driver to cause Bad URL.

Comment: In JDBC4 every capable driver is registered (you shouldn't need to register a driver yourself anymore) and each registered driver is consulted by the `java.sql.DriverManager` to see if it is capable of handling the provided URL.